# Sorting & Merging XML Documents with Perl / XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have many XML files in a directory that need to sorted and merged into one file.  The files are formatted as follows:

*File1.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypea>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>111</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypea>
```

*File2.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypea>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>112</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypea>
```

*File3.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypeb>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>111</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypeb>
```

*File4.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypeb>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>112</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypeb>
```

All the files in this directory need to be sorted on the following criteria:

1. documentnumber
2. doctype (a or b)

Then they need to be merged, so the output file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypea>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>111</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypea>
<doctypeb>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>111</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypeb>
<doctypea>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>112</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypea>
<doctypeb>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>112</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypeb>
```

In order to accomplish this I am trying to use XML:Twig in Perl. I have the following code so far:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $xmldir = "/xmlfiles";
my $parser = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');

opendir(DIR, "$xmldir");
my @FILES= readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach (@FILES) {
        if ($_ ne "." && $_ ne "..") {
                print "reading file: $xmldir/$_\n";
                $parser->parsefile("$xmldir/$_");
        }
}
```

At this point I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax to get the elements I want from the parser.

**1. How do I get the value of the root element ("doctypea" or "doctypeb")?**

**2. I assume I need that (1) in order to parsenode down to the docnumber field?**

My plan then is to build some kind of has with doctype%number in order to sort, I am not sure the easiest way to merge them with that.

Appreciate any advise!

Comment: These are not XML files. They are rejected by XML-Twig and any other XML processor, and rightfully so. Attribute values must be quoted and the names of the start and end tag of each root element must match.

Comment: Sorry that was my manually mocking up a simpler example that made them invalid.  They are valid XML files.  I corrected the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please find below small example that should get you started. It shows how to get data from XML file similar to yours (I fixed the tags to match and quoted `someattr` value to get valid XML). You can use similar approach to gather data you need and produce output.

```
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
    '/*'        => sub { print $_->gi;           },     # doctypea
    'docnumber' => sub { print $_->trimmed_text; },     # 111
})->parse(\*DATA);    # use parsefile('xxx.xml') to parse a file

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctypea>
  <header someattr="1">
    <docnumber>111</docnumber>
  </header>
</doctypea>
```

Comment: When I try this I get:

`unrecognized expression in handler: '/*' `

Comment: @toolic: I'm on perl v5.8.5 (linux) and XML:Twig v 3.13.  I do not have the ability to upgrade these.

Comment: @ChuckMac - `XML::Twig` is pure perl module, so you can just download latest version and put files `Twig.pm` and `Twig/XPath.pm` into directory `XML` in your `PERL5LIB`. This way you could have latest version without updating anything. Per [cpantesters](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=XML-Twig+3.39) this should work fine even on perl 5.8.5.

Comment: @bvr: I was able to put the latest version of XML::Twig in a seperate directory and require it directly and this works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As daxim noticed, your files aren't valid XML, but you could process them using regular expressions.  If the files aren't too big, you could slurp the files into individual strings which you sort based upon their contents.

```
use File::Slurp qw( read_dir ) ;
my $xmldir=".";
my %files = map {
        s/^.*$//m; 
        /<doctype([ab])>/; my $x=ord($1) - ord('a');
        /<docnumber>(\d+)</docnumber>/; $x += 10*$2;
        $x => $_
    } read_dir($xmldir);
print join("", map { $files{$_} } sort keys %files);
```

I have not debugged this code.  Also `print join("", values %files);` might work.

Comment: Sorry that was my manually mocking up a simpler example that made them invalid. They are valid XML files. I corrected the example.

They are much larger than this, I just simplified the objective.